# How Does SVN Client (Tortoise) and server behave if an import operation is disconnected by the server?

Tags: svn, import, tortoisesvn

I am attempting to import a very large directory structure to svn with tortoisesvn. The server disconnected about 1.5 Gigs into the operation.  Do I simply run the import command again?  Will it start back up where it left off?  Or will it start importing all the files all over again?

Comment: given how big the inport is, can you can it on the server with the SVN command line tools, so as to spead it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN uses transactions to ensure that your commits are either completely done or not.
If the server disconnected in the middle of the operation, I'm afraid you will have to restart it from the beginning.

Maybe you could split your import in separate commits (ie., import one subdirectory at a time) ?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with Tortoise, if an operation fails it discards all the changes. I've only ever had it happen by error or cancellation but it should behave the same for a disconnect. If you start the commit again it will have to start from the beginning, but it should be fine.